# Twitter button showing default tweet

Tags: javascript, arrays, twitter

[Here](http://codepen.io/league95/pen/qZBqeM/) is a Random Quote generator app that I need to fix the twitter button. I need to make it so that when ever I click "tweet", it includes both the quote and the author within the tweet. So far it just includes a link. How do I do this?

```
$('#tweetQuote').attr('href', 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text=' + encodeURIComponent('"' + randomQuote + '" ' + randomAuthor));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem stems from the twitter widget that takes the url of the page and replaces it with your being that still do not use the widget itself but use your own function, it would be better to remove the widget twitter and create a button with css (or images), in short, you should create you twitter button and just leave getQuote () function; removing this code:

```
window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```

for the Twitter button you see this: https://gist.github.com/jpwright/2339817

or this: https://www.google.it/search?q=button+twitter&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=1013&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwid_M2S3q_LAhXoIJoKHSNRCjAQ_AUIBigB#tbm=isch&q=button+tweet+png